# CouchDB get changes only from client type "mobile"

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I have **mobile clients** and a **python client** that will make changes to CouchDB.The **python client** is also [listening](https://py-couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#subscribe-to-a-changes-stream-feed) for changes but should get only changes from the **mobile clients**.

So i would make a field in all docs, and if it's "client": "python" then just don't handle the this doc in the listening function.

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CouchDB isn't going to store the source of the document, so your solution of manually maintaining a field with the source in a `client` field sounds like a decent solution.

You may want to experiment whether filtering the `_changes` feed using a JS filter function is faster or slower than just receiving all changes in your python application and filtering there.